# Windows Phone app, Convert.tobase64 gives ArgumentOutOfRange exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

```
Convert.ToBase64CharArray(_imageBytes, 0, 120000, outa, 0);
```

_imagebytes is a byte array coming from a writeable bitmap. If the size is greater than 120000, it throws an ArgumentOutOfRange exception.

Is there a better (or even functioning) way to serialize an image to a character array?

Need to use it to serialize an image to a character array to store it in Azure Mobile Service

Comment: Alternatively, converting to a string works as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base64 encoding stores three bytes in four characters, so you can take parts of the array that is evenly divisible by three and convert separately.

For example, to split the work of converting 10000 bytes into four parts:

```
Convert.ToBase64CharArray(_imageBytes, 0, 3000, outa, 0);
Convert.ToBase64CharArray(_imageBytes, 3000, 3000, outa, 4000);
Convert.ToBase64CharArray(_imageBytes, 6000, 3000, outa, 8000);
Convert.ToBase64CharArray(_imageBytes, 9000, 1000, outa, 12000);
```